# What is happening to such distributed in-memory cloud databases as Hazelcast and Scalris if there is more Data to store than RAM in the cluster?

Tags: database, open-source, cloud, key-value, hazelcast

What is happening to such distributed in-memory cloud databases as

1. [Hazelcast](http://www.hazelcast.com/)
2. [Scalaris](http://code.google.com/p/scalaris/)

if there is more Data to store than RAM in the cluster?

Are they going to Swap? What if the Swap space is full? 
I can't see a disaster recovery strategy at both databases! Maybe all data is lost if the memory is full?

Is there a availability to write things down to the hard-disk for memory issues?
Are there other databases out there, which offer the same functionality as Hazelcast or Scalaris with backup features / hdd-storage / disaster recovery?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I don't know what the state of affairs was when the accepted answer by Martin K. was published, but Scalaris FAQ now claims that this is supported.

[Can I store more data in Scalaris than ram+swapspace is available in the cluster?](http://code.google.com/p/scalaris/wiki/FAQ#Can_I_store_more_data_in_Scalaris_than_ram+swapspace_is_availabl)

> Yes. We have several database
>   backends, e.g. src/db_ets.erl (ets)
>   and src/db_tcerl (tokyocabinet). The
>   former uses the main memory for
>   storing data, while the latter uses
>   tokyocabinet for storing data on disk.
>   With tokycoabinet, only your local
>   disks should limit the total size of
>   your database. Note however, that this
>   still does not provide persistency.
>
> For instructions on switching the
>   database backend to tokyocabinet see
>   [Tokyocabinet](http://code.google.com/p/scalaris/wiki/Tokyocabinet).

Answer (score 3):

Regarding to the teams of Hazelcast and Scalaris, they say both, that writing more Data than RAM is available isn't supported.

The Hazlecast team is going to write a flatfile store in the near future.